# Adding ADO.NET Entity Data Model to Azure function project causes exception

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, azure, azure-functions

I'm converting a webjob (console app) to a azure function: 
So the azure function has a target framework of .Net Framework 4.6.1, and I install entity framework 6.0.0 from NuGet Packet manager, when I add a new item (ADO.Net Entity Data Model) and configure the connection string I get the following error : "Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation", and a log:

```
=====================
10/8/2018 4:18:03 PM
Recoverable
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. --->     Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.ProjectException: The item type 'EntityDeploy' is not supported by this project item provider.
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.ProjectErrorUtilities.ThrowProjectExceptionHelper(Exception innerException, String unformattedMessage, Object[] args)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.ProjectErrorUtilities.ThrowProjectException(String message, Object arg0)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.CpsProjectItem`1.<SetItemTypeAsync>d__25.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.PropertyPages.PageItemTypeProperty.<SetValueAsStringAsync>d__13.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.Implementation.PropertyPages.DynamicTypeBrowseObject.<>c__DisplayClass112_0.<<VSLangProj80-FileProperties2-set_ItemType>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.Implementation.Package.ProjectNode.<>c__DisplayClass569_0.<<Mutate>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading.JoinableTask.CompleteOnCurrentThread()
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.ProjectMultiThreadedService.ExecuteSynchronously(Func`1 asyncAction)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.Implementation.Package.ProjectNode.Mutate(Func`1 asyncAction, Boolean includesFileSystemChange, String telemetryActivity)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.Implementation.PropertyPages.DynamicTypeBrowseObject.VSLangProj80.FileProperties2.set_ItemType(String value)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Telemetry.WindowsErrorReporting.WatsonReport.GetClrWatsonExceptionInfo(Exception exceptionObject)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
at System.Reflection.RuntimePropertyInfo.SetValue(Object obj, Object value, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] index, CultureInfo culture)
at System.Reflection.RuntimePropertyInfo.SetValue(Object obj, Object value, Object[] index)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.Implementation.Package.Automation.OAPropertyInfo.set_Value(Object value)
at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Design.VisualStudio.ModelWizard.ModelObjectItemWizard.RunFinished()
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TemplateWizard.Wizard.Execute(Object application, Int32 hwndOwner, Object[]& ContextParams, Object[]& CustomParams, wizardResult& retval)
at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHRInternal(Int32 errorCode, IntPtr errorInfo)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ErrorHandler.ThrowOnFailure(Int32 hr, Int32[] expectedHRFailure)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.Implementation.Package.ProjectNode.RunWizard(SimpleHierarchyNode parentNode, String itemName, String wizardToRun, IntPtr dlgOwner)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.Implementation.Package.ProjectNode.<AddItemWithSpecificAsync>d__613.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.Implementation.Package.ProjectNode.<>c__DisplayClass476_0.<<AddItem>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading.JoinableTask.CompleteOnCurrentThread()
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading.JoinableTask`1.CompleteOnCurrentThread()
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.ProjectMultiThreadedService.ExecuteSynchronously[T](Func`1 asyncAction)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.Implementation.Package.ProjectNode.<>c__DisplayClass568_0.<HrInvoke>b__0()
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.HResult.Invoke(Func`1 action, IServiceProvider vsShellServiceProvider, IProjectFaultHandlerService projectFaultHandlerService, UnconfiguredProject project)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
t Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.CommonProjectSystemTools.Rethrow(Exception ex)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.ProjectErrorReporting.<>c__DisplayClass6_0.<SubmitErrorReport>b__0()
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.ExceptionFilter.<>c__DisplayClass2_0.<Guard>g__action|0()
at GuardMethodClass.GuardMethod(Func`1 , Func`2 , Func`2 )
===================
```

I have tried reverting to EntityFramework 5, but I get the same results.

I also tried adding the edm in a separate folder.

Only the .edmx , .designer.cs and the .edmx.diagram files get generated; files that are missing: .context.tt, .context.cs, and .tt.

Anyone knows what might be causing this problem?

**ON A SEPARATE NOTE**

I tried to see if the problem was from using the 4.6.1 framework and created a console app with the 4.6.1 framework, and I was able to add the database normally.

**Additional Info !**

The problem might be revolving around entity framework 6, because when trying to build I get errors in `Model.Designer.cs` with the `System.Data.Entity` namespaces. Manually changing all `System.Data.Entity` into `System.Data.Entity.Core` removes the errors, but whenever I update model from database in `Model.edmx` the code gets regenerated...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RMBE7cWDUbM) Genius I found out that visual studio does not properly generate all files when adding a database in an azure function project; this is why I had to add .NET Framework class library as a second project. Add the ADO .NET Entity Data Model in there, then simply add its connection string in the local.settings.json.

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
  "Entities": {
    "ConnectionString": "[…]",
    "ProviderName": "System.Data.EntityCLient"
  }
}
```

*TIP* You have to replace the `&quot;` by a `'` inside the connection string.

Also Don't forget to add the second class library project as dependency to the first one!

Hope that helps!!

**NOTE**

This is for azure functions v1, I you are using azure function v2, then you have to use entity framework core :/